# How to use a MAX or LARGE function to retrieve the latest date entry inside an existing INDEX MATCH formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 sheets. Sheet1 Column A "Product" that lists products being added to inventory. Column B "Stock Date" is the date entry for that particular restock of product.

Since there could be multiple entries for the same product with different dates, I want to be able to retrieve the latest restock entry from said column B "Stock Date" and match it to the corresponding product from Sheet 2 column A "Product" (this list is fixed and its order cannot be altered) and place the date in the next column B "Last Restock". I also want to ignore blank cells so they don't update a latest date entry.

I have hundreds of entries

What I have in Sheet1

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
| Product                  | Stock Date  |
+--------------------------+-------------+
| 131 Pimenton, Picante    | 3-Jul-2019  |
| 046 Comino               | 3-Jul-2019  |
| 412 Paanch Phoron Masala | 3-Jul-2019  |
| 046 Comino               | 5-Jul-2019  |
| 047 Neguila              |             |
| 150 Mostaza Marrón       |             |
| 033 Fenogreco            |             |
| 003 Hinojo               |             |
| 365 Hojas de Neem        | 4-Jul-2019  |
| 002 Casia, Plv           | 4-Jul-2019  |
| 147 Asafoetida, Plv      | 4-Jul-2019  |
| 100 Sumac                | 5-Jul-2019  |
| 001 Canela, Plv          | 5-Jul-2019  |
| 150 Mostaza Marrón       |             |
| 033 Fenogreco            |             |
| 003 Hinojo               | 8-Jul-2019  |
| 365 Hojas de Neem        |             |
| 002 Casia, Plv           |             |
| 147 Asafoetida, Plv      |             |
| 100 Sumac                | 10-Jul-2019 |
| 001 Canela, Plv          | 12-Jul-2019 |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

What I want on Sheet2:

I have tried `INDEX MATCH` with different approaches to where to place the `MAX` or `LARGE` function, to no avail.

`=INDEX(MAX(Sheet1!B:B),MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))`

The result I get with this formula is a `#REF!`

Then another try using the `MAX` function:

`=INDEX(MAX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)),0)`

And these are the results I get:

```
     +-------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
     | Product                       | Last Entry  | Comments | What I Want |
     +-------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
     | 001 Canela, Plv               | 12-Jul-2019 | OK       | 12-Jul-2019 |
     | 002 Casia, Plv                | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 4-Jul-2019  |
     | 003 Hinojo                    | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 8-Jul-2019  |
     | 004 Hinojo Salvaje            | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 005 Polen de Hinojo           | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 006 Anis                      | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 007 Anís Estrellado           | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 008 Regaliz                   | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 008 Regaliz, Plv              | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 009 Clavo de Olor             | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 010 Pimenta Jamaica           | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 011 Vainilla, Madagascar      | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 011 Vainilla, Mexico          | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 011 Vainilla, P. Nueva Guinea | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 012 Tonka                     | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 013 Almendra Amarga           | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 013 Almendra Amarga, Plv      | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 014 Mahlebi                   | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 015 Charoli                   | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 016 Amburana                  | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 017 Sasafrás                  | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 018 Coco Tostado              | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 025 Alcaravea                 | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 026 Eneldo                    | #N/A        | OK       | #N/A        |
     | 033 Fenogreco                 | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    |             |
     | 046 Comino                    | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 5-Jul-2019  |
     | 047 Neguila                   | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    |             |
     | 100 Sumac                     | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 10-Jul-2019 |
     | 131 Pimenton, Picante         | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 3-Jul-2019  |
     | 147 Asafoetida, Plv           | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 4-Jul-2019  |
     | 150 Mostaza Marrón            | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    |             |
     | 365 Hojas de Neem             | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 4-Jul-2019  |
     | 412 Paanch Phoron Masala      | 12-Jul-2019 | Wrong    | 3-Jul-2019  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

As you can see in the "Last Entry" column, it retrieves the latest date but  places it on all the another entries overwriting each particular product's last entry. That's not what I want. I want the latest entry for each particular product.

As you can see I have added 2 more columns "comments" and "what I want" to clarify what I expect from the formula.

Hope this helps,

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you have some data on Sheet1 showing the product name in one column, and stock date for each product in another column, maybe all in random order. Then you have a Sheet2 where you have all product name in one column and you want to look up the last stock date for each product from Sheet1.

If so, you can use a combination of **MAX** and **IF** function to perform the look up in the following logic.

```
{=MAX(IF(Product List=Product Name,Stock Date))}
```

Please note it is an **array formula** so you need to press **CSE** (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to make it work after entering the formula in Excel. This formula needs to be applied in a single cell for each product on Sheet2 and you simply drag the formula down so it finds the date for all products.

Please see below screenshots for more clarification. Please note I have given a **name** to the product list on Sheet1, called it "**Product_List**"; and I have given a **name** to the date list on Sheet1, called it "**Stock_Date**".

Sheet1 Example

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2 Example

[image: Sheet2]

Please note I used a nested IF function to 'ignore' blanks as requested. If you only use the MAX and IF function, it will return '**0/01/1900**' (which is 0) for products that do not have a stock date on Sheet1. If you do not want to show such invalid date then you can use the nested IF function to show a 'blank' cell instead.

Please note, if your original data of product on Sheet1 contains spaces at the end of the name, you will need to create a helper column to clean the product name using **TRIM** function, and reference the helper column in your array formula. Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you Terry, but I'm afraid it didn't work. Needs something else. I believe INDEX MATCH with MAX combined. Apparently I can't post images because of my reputation not high enough.

Comment: Hi Facundo RP, you can upload the image and post a link of the image, then we can click on the link to view it. Or admin can help you edit your post to show the image once you have uploaded it and put a link in your post.

Comment: Thanks Terry I just formatted the text so you can see it as a table, hope it helps. Salute!

Comment: Hi Facundo RP, I have edited my answer and I think the combination of MAX and IF is still working. Not sure why you are so certain the MAX and IF is not working for you. I guess your data might need some 'cleaning'? Or maybe you did not apply the array formula in a singe cell for each line of product? If you worked out where went wrong please let me know :)

Comment: Terry Ace! It works! I've been messing with this formula for the last couple of days. Thanks a lot! Love this exchange

Comment: @Facundo RP Then you might want to mark this answer as solution.

Comment: @OverflowStacker Done! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks folks. I actually want to see if anyone can come up a more elegant way of hiding the 0 value instead of using a nested IF function. Or maybe there is other combinations of formulas that can do the trick in a more concise way.

Comment: You can supress displaying zero's in cells in the settings. I'm too looking for a solution for this kind of problem. I proposed a formula called [IFCONDITION](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/35258329-ifcondition)  which would be similar to `IFERROR`.